# GNU debugger doesn't show all data in C++ structure

Tags: c++, debugging, gnu

I have been using the WinPcap library with C++, Codelite and GNU development tools. I have an IP4 structure describing an IP header. When I cast the packet data into the structure, I can't see all of it in the debugger, just random bits of data.  For example, the source and destination addresses in the IP4 struct don't show up in the debugger, but when I run `printf` statements they show up perfectly fine.  Why is the debugger doing this?  Does the data type in the struct matter? I find it a hassle to `printf` the structs to make sure that the data is valid.  MinGW-4.4.1 and GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1

Comment: Does everything you're trying to look at have debug info attached?  That's where I'd start looking.

Comment: As JimR said, you'll need to make sure your code, and the winpcap library all are compiled with debug symbols included (-g option in most compilers).   Some build tools will also `strip` them out in post build steps, so make sure thats not the case.

Comment: ya i have the -g option enabled on my C++ compiler. But I'm not sure about debugging symbols in the winpcap lib. I simply downloaded the windows exe and installed the lib that way.

Comment: Different compilers can generate non compatible debug symbols.  Debug libraries built with GCC won't show "debug = yes" in Dependency Walker whereas Visual Studio's objects would.   If you want a full debug build you're likely going to have to compile winpcap yourself.  Most distributions don't ship their binaries/dll's with debug symbols in, since theres no point to it.   Unless it specifically calls out that its for development usage...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should recompile the winpcap library with -gstabs+ gcc option. That will allow you to view the library in the debugger. This option adds debug symbols that are understood only by gdb (and other debuggers will crash), but provides the most comprehensive way to view the code.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger cares about the type of the data structure. You will see the full data in the debugger only if you use the correct data type.